error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component when creating a new file
Hello I need your help with this problem of mine, when I try to create a new project in Visual Studio
from ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) >> MVC >> Create it will show the error "error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component" and when I look for the files of the said project it's there but I can't access it.
I tried reinstalling the IDE, same problem
Restarted my computer
Tried deleting the .vs folder, same problem
double checked if the file location for the dowloaded cache (I don't know if this will matter?)

ASP.NET, .NET Framework, C++. One is odd here. You might want C#?

Has nothing to do with C++, so I removed the tag. Also this is more a question for a microsoft (visual studio) forum.

I also tested the creation process according to your steps. I used VS2022 and did not find the same problem. This error is related to COM components. You may need to check the Visual Studio log for more detailed information. Suggestion: Use the
devenv.exe /log
command to generate a log file in
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio<version number>\ActivityLog.xml
to see if there is more information to share. Or select More>Repair in the VS installer to see if the problem is improved.
